# Create FTP Server From Azure VM

Tags: azure, ftp, azure-virtual-machine

I create FTP Server from my Azure Virtual Machine and try the private IP address ftp://10.0.0.5 and it works then when I try the public IP address it says that "Entering Passive Mode"

[image: FTP Folder Error]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Though your question is [off-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are accessing the FTP server on Azure VM by Windows File Explorer in `Passive` mode which required FTP server open another port for connecting in client side again after client connect server on port `21` firstly, but FTP server has no permission to add the new port to NSG inbound rules.

So the solution is to off the Passive Mode in client side to force use `PORT/Active` mode to connect FTP server. You can refer to the existing SuperUser thread https://superuser.com/questions/249731/ftp-from-windows-explorer-in-active-mode to fix it.

Here is my steps in Windows 10, as the figures below.

Fig 1. Click `Search` button and type `Internet Options` to open it

[image]

Fig 2. Select `Advanced` tab and find `Use Passive FTP ...` option to disable it

[image]

Then, you can try to access your FTP server again.

Any concern, please feel free to let me know.

---

Update: for using `FtpWebRequest` to connect FTP server on Azure VM with `PORT/Active` mode, you have to add a code to disable `Passive` mode for `FtpWebRequest` in C# before use it, as below.

```
ftpWebRequest.UsePassive = false;
```

Please refer to the document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ftpwebrequest.usepassive?view=netframework-4.7.2 to know it.

Comment: Hi sir Peter Pan i have problem to my application when accessing my ftp FtpWebResponse = CType(ftp.GetResponse, FtpWebResponse)

Comment: @confidentialaccount I have update my post to answer the same issue when using `FtpWebRequest` in C#.